# Heat pump operation when cold question

Tags: pump, heat

this morning it was 23 degrees F. The indoor unit was on and delivering heat. I looked out at my outdoor unit and the fan was not running but the compressor was. I panicked and pulled the quick disconnect. Later I put it back in and the unit ran normally (fan on, compressor on, etc). I did not feel excessive heat from the compressor but I did see what looked like some king of vapor?smoke coming out, just a little. Did not smell at all.

Question. Is that an efficiency thing for a outdoor heat pump unit to cycle off the fan? I'm a commercial HVAC guy and have zip experience with heat pumps other than theory of operation.

Comment: What type of heat pump? There's a big difference in how a cold climate unit (most of which seem to be mini-splits, though I'm not sure that's in any way required) handles low temperatures and how a "mostly air conditioning but can lamely heat if it's not too cold" (usually central) unit does. A central unit might have been doing pure backup resistance heating at 23F. Either type of unit might have been running a defrost cycle. Cold climate units will effectively heat down to sub-zero Fahrenheit temperatures, while "regular" ones commonly give up somewhere in the 30s and switch to backup heat.

Answer (score 3):

When heating below 32 °F or 0 °C frost forms on the outdoor coils of a heat pump - and that can happen when the air temperature is above that point, if the coils are that cold to collect heat from cold air.

The controller has some logic which either detects or assumes frost formation and kicks into defrost mode to melt the frost so that airflow is restored. Depending on the unit it may engage resistance heating while doing that.

Water vapor ("steam") would be an expected side effect from that process.

Comment: OH crap! completely forgot defrost! Although it's bone dry here there would have to be some. Does the fan (outdoor) turn off in defrost? THANK YOU!

Comment: @RetiredAndRusty -- I'm not sure actually, it may be though

Comment: I don't know for SURE, but I suspect it would shut the fan off, since the point is to melt the frost by applying heat to the coil, and that would be harder with the fan running than without.

Answer (score 2):

The fan in the outdoor unit does not run when the outdoor unit is defrosting since you need a hot refrigerant gas in the coil to do the defrosting. With the fan off and not blowing cold air across the coil the refrigerant is being compressed at a very high pressure causing it to heat up to defrost the coil. This is all accomplished by timers and sensors Inside the outdoor unit is a 4 way valve that switches that unit to cooling (A/C) to do the defrosting and the air delivery in the house is heated by the electric coils in the furnace discharge.